# there is no canonical answer

Tags: discussion

What is to be so bad about question that to have *there is no canonical answer*?

Some time it is important information and super answers and you to be closing it. A pity.

I not to understand; a lot of good project management information is not canonical.

Comment: Hi Issy! Could you please add links to a few examples to understand better how we can clarify your question? Thanks! We had a similar discussion in https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/are-terminology-comparison-related-questions-on-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions that don't have potentially-canonical answers aren't a good fit for this site's Q&A format. That doesn't mean those discussions aren't worthwhile; it just means that Stack Exchange in general, and Project Management Stack Exchange in particular, are not the right places to hold them.